# Workspace created by cocoapods is locked

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I'm using CocoaPods with a project. I ran `pod install` and it installed correctly. Then when I try to open the created `xcworkspace` Xcode displaying the error 'workspace file is locked'. I tried to unlock it but it's not working. It also didn't include some frameworks (Security.framework, MobileCoreServices.framework etc.) in workspace.

Comment: The [CocoaPods issues page](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues) might be a more appropriate place for this.

Comment: How can you tell the workspace isn't include the frameworks if it can't be opened? Also which version of Xcode are you using? Are you the owner of the created workspace? This could be a permissions issue?

Comment: @KeithSmiley I am using Xcode 4.6. By clicking don't unlock button in error dialog I am able to open the project. But its not compiling and also its not contain required frameworks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had this problem recently. I don't know about the missing frameworks, but if you go to your project folder within terminal and modify the permissions on the project files, you should be able to open the project. I personally had to modify multiple files and folders to be able to get it to stop asking me if I want to unlock my files.

Steps that Worked for Me:

Use the terminal to go to the folder that contains the xcworkspace file. Type

```
sudo chmod 777 NameOfYourWorkspaceFile.xcworkspace
```

(Please don't literally use that file name unless that's what your xcworkspace file is called). This should change the permissions for your entire workspace, but you will still have the unlock problem with your Pods project.

From within the same directory, you can do another chmod on the Pods folder like so:

```
sudo chmod 777 Pods
```

After that, go into your Pods folder by typing "cd Pods" and then modify the permissions on your Pods.xcodeproj file as so:

```
sudo chmod 777 Pods.xcodeproj
```

Like I said previously, these permission changes were enough to get xCode to stop asking me if I want to unlock my projects. I don't know if it will be enough for you though. Hopefully it helps!

Comment: It could be the user/group is incorrect rather than the permissions. On my attempt at installation, I noticed everything 'pod' was owned by root instead of the user.

Comment: I am having the same problem. How can I fix the group/user permissions?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same 'locked workspace' problem.

The root of my problem was that I was running `sudo pod install` instead of `pod install`. 
If I ran `pod install` I got:

```
[!] Pod::Executable pull 
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
```

The problem is that running `sudo pod install`, the root is creating the .xcworkspace and when you open it with your user, it says that the project is locked.

What I did was change the permissions to be able to run `pod install` by doing:

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.cocoapods
```

Changing these permissions, the command `pod install` should work and the generated .xcworkspace should not be locked.

I hope this helps someone!